# Get WMIC Bytes Received/Sent to match count in Windows Network Status Interface

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, network-adapter, wmic

I'm using the following WMIC query in `cmd` to get the number of bytes sent/received over the network:

```
wmic path Win32_PerfRawDataTcpip_NetworkInterface get BytesReceivedPersec, BytesSentPersec
```

My goal is to get the count to match the bytes sent/received count displayed in the Network Connections Ethernet Status. 
Here's a screenshot of the Network Interface Values I'm trying to match:

[image: Network Status Activity Interface Screenshot]

The issue is whenever I run the WMIC command, I receive byte counts that are slightly above the count values displayed in the Network Status Interface.

I was looking at the [WMIC Documentation here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa394340(v=vs.80)), and it says the byte values returned include the framing characters as well as the byte count. 
So...

1. Is the addition of the framing characters causing the WMIC query to return higher values than the Network Activity Interface?
2. If so, is it possible to query the framing characters using WMIC or a similar cmd line tool to subtract them from the WMIC sent/received count in order to match the Network Activity values?

Comment: You could try to loop read bytes via netsh `netsh interface ip show subinterfaces "%iface_name%" |findstr "%iface_name%"` and timestamp with precision of centiseconds `echo %time%` and computate traffic flow from time aby bytes difference

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but... Correct name of the class is `Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface`.

To get available class and counters you can follow by next steps:

1. Run `%windir%\system32\wbem\wbemtest.exe`
2. Push `Connect` and input `root\cimv2`
3. Push `Open Class...` and input `Win32_PerfRawData` (or any known class).
4. Push `Derived`. Select required class by double click.
5. Set `Hide system properties` flag and below you will see available props.